# Are these logical operators?

Tags: javascript, arrays, operators, logical-operators

JavaScript:

```
        //variable to hold total price of shopping cart
        var cart_total_price=0;
        //iterate over array of objects
        for(var product in shoppingCart){
        //add new row      
        var row=orderedProductsTblBody.insertRow();
        //create three cells for product properties 
        var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
        var cellDescription = row.insertCell(1);
        var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);
        cellPrice.align="right";
        //fillS the cells with values from current product object of our 
        array
        cellName.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Name;
        cellDescription.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Description;
        cellPrice.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Price;
        cart_total_price+=shoppingCart[product].Price;
        }
        //fill total cost of our shopping cart 
        document.getElementById("cart_total").innerHTML=cart_total_price;
```

Hi guys, im not sure if the "=" sign counts as a logical operator?? Also i feel like "+=" is one but im not entirely sure what it means?

Comment: do you have an issue with the code? what is your question?

Comment: Both are assignment operators.
+= means addition assignment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

Comment: is the "+=" a logical operator? If so, what is its purpose within that line(near the bottom)? The code is working fine

Comment: According to [this MDN article on logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), the only three logical operators are `||` (OR), `&&` (AND) and `!` (NOT)

Answer (score 2):

'=','+=' are assignment operators.

x += y; means x = x + y;

if x=5 and y=7 then x += y means x=12;

Logical Operators are -

&&  and
||  or
!   not